# Game function in tkinter(turn based)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI for a turn based game, I want one button to say player attack which would then minus a random integer between two set points from another label called monster health. Currently I have set the numbers as normal rather than random to more clearly demonstrate my problem.

I have tried changing formats and importing code from current game file into GUI programme

```
from Tkinter import *
import random 

root = Tk()

def phealth():     #playerhealth
    (100) 
def mhealth(): #monsterhealth
    (99)
def pheal():    #playerheal
    (rand.randint(10))
def mheal(): #monsterheal
    (10)
def pattackf(): #player attack value
    (10) 
def mattackf(): #monster attack value
    (10) 
def attackm(): #attack monster
    (mhealth-pattackf)
def attackp(): #attack player
   (phealth-mattackf)
def healhm(): #heal monster
    (mhealth+mheal)
def healp(): #heal player
    (phealth+pheal)
def middleClick(event):
    mhealth=attackm

print('welcome to monsterland, try not to die')
print('It is time to name your character, what would you like to be called?')
player1= raw_input()

playername = Label(root, text = "PLAYER NAME: " + str.upper(player1), fg="Red")
playername.grid(row=0, column= 2, sticky= "E")

attack = Label(root, text= "Attack Monster")
attack.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="W")

attackbutton = Button(root, text = 10)
attackbutton.grid(row=0,column=1)


heal = Label(root, text= "Heal Self")
heal.grid(row=1,column=0, sticky="W")

healbutton = Button(root, text = 12)
healbutton.grid(row=1,column=1)

playerhealth = Label(root, text= "Player Health")
playerhealth.grid(row=2,column=0, sticky="W")

phealthdisplay = Label(root,text= 100)
phealthdisplay.grid(row=2,column=1)


monsterhealth = Label(root, text= "Monster Health")
monsterhealth.grid(row=3,column=0, sticky="W")

mhealthdisplay = Label(root, text= 100)
mhealthdisplay.grid(row=3,column=1)





root.geometry('500x500')
#root.configure(background='Red')


root.mainloop()
```

---

I would like to be able to press player attack and minus from mhealthdisplay I would also like to press player heal and plus heal button value to player health the def functions above are attempts that I have used in equations though have removed as they don't work left up there to demonstrate current attempts. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions like the following have no effect. I added some comments

```
def mattackf(): #monster attack value
    (10) 
    # (10) is just the same as if you write 10
    # it creates an int object with value 10
    # and does nothing with it
    # I guess you wanted to assign 10 to a 
    # variable called attackf (see my suggestion)

def attackm(): #attack monster
    (mhealth-pattackf)
# this code subtracts what is named pattackf
# from what is named mhealt
# in your case both are functions
# if you want to execute this code, you have
# to call it like with
# attackm()
# this will rais an error and say, that it can't
# subtract a function from another function
# I guess you wanted to decrease mhealth (see below)
```

I guess you rather wanted to:

```
# define phealth and mhealth to be the variables 
# of the health value with which you can calculate
# and set them to 100/99, then you would do:
phealth= 100
mhealth= 99

# use a fixed value whenever the heal button for
# the monster is pressed and a random value to
# be used whenever the heal button for the player 
# is used:
mheal=    10

def pheal():    #playerheal
    return rand.randint(1, 10)

# now the functions to apply those heal values:

def healhm(): #heal monster
    # the global statement tells python that
    # you work with the globally defined variables
    # otherwise it would assume, that the
    # variables are only visible in the function
    global mhealth, mheal
    # add the value in mheal to the value of mhealth
    # and store the result in mhealth
    mhealth= mhealth + mheal

def healp(): #heal player
    # again tell python that pheal is a global name
    global phealth
    print 'healing player', phealth
    # like for mheal, but this time we
    # call pheal() and add it's return
    # value to phealth
    phealth= phealth + pheal()

def attackm(): #attack monster
    global mhealth, pattackf
    mhealth= mhealth-pattackf
```

Now you just need to make sure, your buttons call your functions. The code for this looks like:

```
attackbutton = Button(root, text = 10, command=lambda: attackm())
attackbutton.grid(row=0,column=1)

healbutton = Button(root, text = 12, command=lambda:healp())
healbutton.grid(row=1,column=1)
```

If you want to get rid of the input statement, so the user does not have to switch between console and gui, you can just add:

```
v_pname= tk.StringVar()
v_pname.set('Enter the Name here')

playerentry= Entry(root, textvariable=v_pname)
playerentry.grid(row=0, column= 3, sticky= "E")
```

Remove the line with `input_raw` and change the line with the player label like:

```
playername = Label(root, text = "PLAYER NAME:", fg="Red")
playername.grid(row=0, column= 3, sticky= "W")
```

One more advice:
You seem to be using Pyhton2. If you are learning Python nowadays, you should consider learning Python3 directly. So if you find your tutorial in Python3 as well, try to switch to this version, if not, you can also continue with Python2, but you might not find all your libraries, you need later because the support for Python2 is decreasing. Unfortunately Python2 and Python3 have some bigger differences. E.g. printing something to console is done differently, also other parts are a bit different (like input, range, and dividing by integers). If you learn directly in Python3 you won't need to relearn what is different.

Comment: I appreciate the response, thank you I managed to get this working before I got a respond from Stack but it’s a welcoming start to joining the community! Cheers